# How to assess the quality and goodness of fit of a lasso model?

Tags: linear-model, residuals, lasso, goodness-of-fit, regularization

So far I evaluate the lasso model by its out-of-sample predictions and by the $R^2$ for the goodness of fit. What other measures should I look at? Particularly, do I need to examine the residuals for certain attributes?

Edit: The point of the evaluation is not model selection so in my understanding measures like AIC or BIC are not relevant

Comment: Lasso is an estimation technique, not a model. For a given model, you assess the model fit just as you normally would. What you do now seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can check residuals of regularised models (L1, L2) as you would for normal regression models.

Keep in mind though that regularisation creates a bias towards zero on the regression estimates. If you now plot residuals against predictions or predictors, you may see a bottom-left to top-right residual patterns. This is because the zero-bias from the regularisation tends to cause overestimation for small and underestimation for high values. Such a pattern is expected and not an indicator of model misspecification.

Btw: the same happens when you plot residuals against predictions made with a random effect, because random effect estimates are in some sense L2 regularised (because of the underlying normal distribution, which creates an adaptive shrinkage on the RE estimates, identical to L2). See example here https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/issues/43